# Printing a string, which contains the image name, using a <img> tag on JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jquery-mobile, jstl, struts-1

I have a string named `strImage` which contains the image name like: http://m.sears.com/ecircular/SearsLocalAd.jpg and I need to print this images on my JSP. I am using the below 2 code lines to print the image:

```
<img src="<%=strImage%>" alt="Test Image 1" width="270" height="190"/>
```

and I also used

```
<img src="<c:url value="<%=strImage%>"/> alt="Test Image 1" width="270" height="190"/>
```

but I was unable to print the image. Please suggest how to print the images.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try also

```
<img src="<%= out.print(strImage); %>" alt="Test Image 1" width="270" height="190"/>
```

?

Comment: Ya , i tried but <img src="<%= out.print(strImage); %>" alt="Test Image 1" width="270" height="190"/> also didn't work, any other solution?

Comment: i think strImage value is not correct, try passing the path from the folder that contains your jpf file. For example if you have a folder <src> which contains all jsp files and another folder <images> inside it which contains all images you should use ./image/SearchLocalAd.jpg as strImage value.